# iOS Comic Reader - Is this a viable design?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Because of an imminent deadline, I'm looking for the easiest viable way to put together a Comic Reader app.

My current design is as follows:

- Each Page is a subclass of `UIViewController`, containing a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`.
- Tapping the right side of the screen pushes another Page onto the `UINavigationController`.

With this basic scheme, I would be pushing 20+ `UIViewController`s on top of each other, one for each page.

My question is: is this an abuse of `UIViewController`s, or an inadvisable solution?

What I would *rather* do, I think, is have one `UIViewController` that moves around some subviews which contain the page contents. But if the above idea is viable, it would be easier -- I wouldn't have to manually write any of the page transitioning logic & animation, simply push.

I am new to iOS and trying to learn enough to find the best solution in the timeframe I have, so any help or direction is greatly appreciated. Setting the app up this way is obviously not prohibited, but after learning that instantiating a ViewController, then using its .view in another `UIViewController` (which I do in another part of the app), is really bad practice, I'm doubting my understanding of how `UIViewController`s should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you may think this is an abuse, maybe memory-wise talking? or maybe that this is not the most elegant way to solve this?

This is certainly not the best way to solve this issue, I'm sure that the OS will have no problem handling this (for older versions of the hardware, I can imagine some glitches). Try for instance doing something abusive in the Twitter iOS app, go to your profile, then see one of your tweets, then go to the profile of that tweet or something like that, again and again and again. Or go through different profiles and tweets, I have seen that the memory management is pretty great. So you won't have to worry about the memory as long as you implement the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method.

From the UIViewController class [reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Memory Management**
>
> Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide
>   built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical
>   times. The UIViewController class provides some automatic handling of
>   low-memory conditions through its didReceiveMemoryWarning method,
>   which releases unneeded memory. Prior to iOS 3.0, this method was the
>   only way to release additional memory associated with your custom view
>   controller class but in iOS 3.0 and later, the viewDidUnload method
>   may be a more appropriate place for most needs.
>
> When a low-memory warning occurs, the UIViewController class purges
>   its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If
>   this happens, it also calls the viewDidUnload method to give your code
>   a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated
>   with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded with the nib file,
>   objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily
>   at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. Typically, if your view
>   controller contains outlets (properties or raw variables that contain
>   the IBOutlet keyword), you should use the viewDidUnload method to
>   relinquish ownership of those outlets or any other view-related data
>   that you no longer need.

Now, if I had the time to implement another solution, I would probably design a model with all the contents from each view something like.

**Model**

- Title (`NSString`).
- PagePaths (`NSArray`).
- CurrentIndex (`int`).
- TransitionType (`ComicBookTransitionType`).

**View**

- MainView (`UIViewController`).
- MyModel (`ComicBookModel`).
- NextPage (`UIView`). (I would probably have this pre-loaded to guarantee a smooth transition from page to page, so as the next property).
- PreviousPage (`UIView`).

Something like that, all that would be left to do (and the real tricky part) is to change the value from the MainView to the NextPage or to the Previous Page.

And another option is to go for the [Ebook Framework](http://bakerframework.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas & reassurance that this is at least valid, even if not optimal. 

I think I found a good reference for this in Apple's sample app, [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html), which lazy-loads a ScrollView with the views of several ViewControllers, and I think it puts me on the right track for a more sound design. The pagination provided by a ScrollView should make the transition between "Main, Next, & Previous" easier, especially with their sample code for lazy loading.